# Getting ORA-00942 Error for "Table or View does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure why, but referenced tabled not able to be identified. The following is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Store (
    Store_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Dept_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Manager_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Employee_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Store_PK PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Manager_FK FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID) REFERENCES Manager (Manager_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Employee_FK FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES Employee (Employee_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Manager
(
    Manager_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Employee_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Manager_Lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Manager_Fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Manager_PK PRIMARY KEY (Manager_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Employee_FK FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES Employee (Employee_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderTable
(
    Order_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Customer_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Vendor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Product_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Tracking_Num NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Customer_FK FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Vendor_FK FOREIGN KEY (Vendor_ID) REFERENCES Vendor (Vendor_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Product_FK FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES Product (Product_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Shipping_FK FOREIGN KEY (Tracking_Num) REFERENCES Shipping (Tracking_Num)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Customer_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Customer_Lname VARCHAR(30),
    Customer_Fname VARCHAR(30),
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Payment_Type VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Product
(
    Product_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Price NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Brand VARCHAR(30),
    Classification VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT Product_PK PRIMARY KEY (Product_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Employee_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Title INT,
    Employee_Lname VARCHAR(30),
    Employee_Fname VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Vendor
(
    Vendor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    Product_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Quantity NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT Vendor_PK PRIMARY KEY (Vendor_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Product_FK FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES Product (Product_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Retail
(
    Retail_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Product_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Vendor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Order_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Price NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Quantity NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Retail_PK PRIMARY KEY (Retail_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Product_FK FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES Product (Product_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Vendor_FK FOREIGN KEY (Vendor_ID) REFERENCES Vendor (Vendor_ID),
    CONSTRAINT OrderTable_FK FOREIGN KEY (Order_ID) REFERENCES OrderTable (Order_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Shipping
(
    Tracking_Num NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    Order_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Vendor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    Address VARCHAR2(50),
    Shipping_Date NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Shipping_PK PRIMARY KEY (Tracking_Num),
    CONSTRAINT OrderTable_FK FOREIGN KEY (Order_ID) REFERENCES OrderTable (Order_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Vendor_FK FOREIGN KEY (Vendor_ID) REFERENCES Vendor (Vendor_ID)
);
```

Comment: Tables need to be defined before they are referenced in foreign key constraints.  I think the error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the order you're creating your tables, this is likely your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Store ( 
    ...
    CONSTRAINT Manager_FK FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID) 
         REFERENCES Manager (Manager_ID)
    ...
```

You're referencing a table in your table definition that doesn't exist yet.